# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'

Tags: python, linux, консоль, flask

Пыталась скачать через pip/pip3, также скачивала unixODBC и iODBC

```
(venv) [dir]# pip3 --proxy  install pyodbc
Requirement already satisfied: pyodbc in ./lib64/python3.6/site-packages (4.0.30)
(venv) [dir]# flask run
```

Но при запуске flask пишет, что такого модуля нет.

```
 * Serving Flask app "run.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: While importing "run", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/kpi_bases/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/var/www/путь/run.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/var/www/путь/app.py", line 10, in <module>
    import pyodbc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'
```

В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Возможно модуль установлен в виртуальное окружение, а flask запускаете системным python.

Answer (score 1):

Сложно сказать. Вы видимо работаете с проектами на Flask. Все зависит от настроек проекта. Рабочий каталог и виртуальная среда для приложения.
Если просто надо установить например в Ubuntu:
sudo python3 -m pip search pyodbc
[image: search pyodbc]

sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-dev g++ unixodbc-dev
sudo python3 -m pip install pyodbc

[image: install pyodbc]